# Addressing properties of a Shockwave Flash object (MultiPowUpload) in JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, flash, shockwave

Please pardon the dumb newbie question; I've only been programming Javascript for about 24 hours... :)

I have managed (with some outside help) to embed a shockwave flash object into my page - specifically [MultiPowUpload 2.1](http://www.element-it.com/MultiPowUpload.aspx).  It's appearing nicely on the page and seems to be functioning correctly; we can take that part as read.

Now I'm trying to do some more advanced stuff in JavaScript - I have a button, and in the `onClick()` code I have the following:

```
var swf = document.getElementById("FlashFilesUpload1");
var itemsCount = swf.filesCount;
alert("items: "+itemsCount);
```

But the alert statement tells me "items: undefined".  It does the same if I set `itemsCount` to `swf.nonExistentProperty` - everything is "undefined".  But from what I read in the [documentation](http://www.element-it.com/OnlineHelpMulti/index.html), there definitely is a `filesCount` property.  I tried accessing all the other properties and methods of this swf object, and none of them work, except for `toString()`, which returns "HTMLObjectElement".

I am obviously addressing this object incorrectly - but what am I doing wrong?

---

### Clarification

In response to [@brianpeiris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838621/addressing-properties-of-a-shockwave-flash-object-multipowupload-in-javascript/838754#838754): I am doing this quite differently from the page at the [link you suggested](http://www.element-it.com/Examples/MultiPowUpload/AdvancedHTMLinterface.html).  I didn't do this with any great knowledge, I'm just really acting like a monkey, trying to copy other people's code that works, then tweak it so it does what I want... so don't assume I know anything, however obvious - remember, I've only been doing JavaScript for about a day now!

So here's the code for the control itself:

```
          <object id="FlashFilesUpload1" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0"
          classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" viewastext>
          <!-- Replace symbols " with the &quot; at all parameters values and 
    symbols "&" with the "%26" at URL values or &amp; at other values!
    The same parameters values should be set for EMBED object below. -->
          <param name="FlashVars" value="uploadButtonVisible=false&uploadUrl=../ReceiveBulkCases.aspx" />
          <param name="BGColor" value="#F8F6E6" />
          <param name="Movie" value="ClientSideControls/ElementITMultiPowUpload2.1.swf" />
          <param name="Src" value="ClientSideControls/ElementITMultiPowUpload2.1.swf" />
          <param name="WMode" value="Window" />
          <param name="Play" value="-1" />
          <param name="Loop" value="-1" />
          <param name="Quality" value="High" />
          <param name="SAlign" value="" />
          <param name="Menu" value="-1" />
          <param name="Base" value="" />
          <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always" />
          <param name="Scale" value="ShowAll" />
          <param name="DeviceFont" value="0" />
          <param name="EmbedMovie" value="0" />
          <param name="SWRemote" value="" />
          <param name="MovieData" value="" />
          <param name="SeamlessTabbing" value="1" />
          <param name="Profile" value="0" />
          <param name="ProfileAddress" value="" />
          <param name="ProfilePort" value="0" />
          <!-- Embed for Netscape,Mozilla/FireFox browsers support. Flashvars parameters are the same.-->
          <!-- Replace symbols " with the &quot; at all parameters values and symbols "&" with the "%26" at URL values or &amp; at other values! -->
          <embed bgcolor="#F8F6E6" id="EmbedFlashFilesUpload" src="ClientSideControls/ElementITMultiPowUpload2.1.swf"
            quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="450" height="350" flashvars="uploadButtonVisible=false&uploadUrl=../ReceiveBulkCases.aspx">
</embed>
        </object>
```

As you see it's embedded in the HTML as an `object`, unlike the reference you gave, where they do some other trick using script to get it onto the page.

BTW, when I tried it their way (not very hard, I grant you), I didn't manage to get the control even to appear on my page!

Thanks for your help... much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** I think I finally figured it out! You simply have set the `useExternalInterfaces` to `Yes`.

So in your code you would change

```
<param 
  name="FlashVars"
  value="uploadButtonVisible=false&uploadUrl=../ReceiveBulkCases.aspx" />
```

to

```
<param 
  name="FlashVars"
  value="uploadButtonVisible=false&uploadUrl=../ReceiveBulkCases.aspx&useExternalInterface=Yes" />
```

and do the same for the `<embed>` tag.

If you visit the [demo site](http://www.element-it.com/Examples/MultiPowUpload/AdvancedHTMLinterface.html) and run the following code in Firebug it returns `0` before you select files and the correct count after you select files. Also, if you check the source, you'll see that the `useExternalInterface` option is set to `Yes`

```
alert(document.getElementById('MultiPowUpload').filesCount());
```

**P.S.** You should consider using the SWFObject script included with MultiPowUpload. It lets you set and change variables easily without having to worry about cross-browser issues and it also degrades gracefully for users without flash.

---

**Further edit**
To answer your comment: Yes, I've got `filesCount` working on my machine.

One thing I forgot to mention is that you might be trying to retrieve `filesCount` before the flash control is fully loaded.

The following is the code I'm using. I copied your code exactly and added the `useExternalInterface` setting as well as my own javascript.

Note that my javascript code repeatedly checks the `filesCount` every 500 milliseconds using the `setInterval` function.

```
<object id="FlashFilesUpload1" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0"
  classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" viewastext>
  <!-- Replace symbols " with the &quot; at all parameters values and
  symbols "&" with the "%26" at URL values or &amp; at other values!
  The same parameters values should be set for EMBED object below. -->
  <param name="FlashVars" value="uploadButtonVisible=false&uploadUrl=../ReceiveBulkCases.aspx&useExternalInterface=Yes" />
  <param name="BGColor" value="#F8F6E6" />
  <param name="Movie" value="ClientSideControls/ElementITMultiPowUpload2.1.swf" />
  <param name="Src" value="ClientSideControls/ElementITMultiPowUpload2.1.swf" />
  <param name="WMode" value="Window" />
  <param name="Play" value="-1" />
  <param name="Loop" value="-1" />
  <param name="Quality" value="High" />
  <param name="SAlign" value="" />
  <param name="Menu" value="-1" />
  <param name="Base" value="" />
  <param name="AllowScriptAccess" value="always" />
  <param name="Scale" value="ShowAll" />
  <param name="DeviceFont" value="0" />
  <param name="EmbedMovie" value="0" />
  <param name="SWRemote" value="" />
  <param name="MovieData" value="" />
  <param name="SeamlessTabbing" value="1" />
  <param name="Profile" value="0" />
  <param name="ProfileAddress" value="" />
  <param name="ProfilePort" value="0" />
  <!-- Embed for Netscape,Mozilla/FireFox browsers support. Flashvars parameters are the same.-->
  <!-- Replace symbols " with the &quot; at all parameters values and symbols "&" with the "%26" at URL values or &amp; at other values! -->
  <embed bgcolor="#F8F6E6" id="EmbedFlashFilesUpload" src="ClientSideControls/ElementITMultiPowUpload2.1.swf"
    quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash"
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="450" height="350" flashvars="uploadButtonVisible=false&uploadUrl=../ReceiveBulkCases.aspx&useExternalInterface=Yes">
  </embed>
</object>


<script>
  function updateMessage() {
    var message = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString() + ': ';

    try {
      var objectElement = document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0];
      var embedElement = document.getElementsByTagName('embed')[0];

      if (objectElement.filesCount) {
        message += 'We are in IE ' + objectElement.filesCount();
      }
      else if (embedElement.filesCount) {
        message += 'We are in Firefox ' + embedElement.filesCount();
      }
      else {
        message += "The flash object is not loaded or useExternalInterface is not set to 'Yes'";
      }
    }
    catch (exp) {
      message += 'An error occurred';
    }
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = message;
  }

  // Update the message every 500 milliseconds
  setInterval(updateMessage, 500);
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, you're right I should have realized that. From what you've said so far, it should work. Are you trying to access filesCount *before* you select files? Are you sure "FlashFilesUpload1" is the correct id for the flash object (especially if you are using multiple upload objects). It would help if you provided some sample HTML and javascript

Comment: Nope, that didn't make any difference... :(  In any case, the default value of useExternalInterface is true.  I'll try the object script provided by MultiPowUpload, see where that gets me... 
BTW, even if it's still not working out, your help is REALLY appreciated - THANK YOU!

Comment: Well, I managed to get the control working using the embedSWF() stuff from the website, as suggested - but the javascript interface still doesn't work... I can't get a single member of the MultiPowUpload interface to work - not properties, not methods - and it doesn't seem to make any difference whether I do it by embedding it as an <object> or using embedSWF().  Did you manage to get it to respond to javascript calls, even in a simple "Hello World" type test?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the code that I'm using to make it work. My code doesn't work if you don't set the useExternalInterface to Yes explicitly. Perhaps the documentation is wrong about it being true by default.